# Why might RMI be a sensible option for communication between client and server in a web application?

Tags: architecture, communication

Question: **Why might RMI be a sensible option for communication between client and server in a web application?**

*So why would RMI be used for communication between client and server in web apps?*

Comment: What do you mean by sensible option?

Comment: The format of the question suggests this may come from a book, and is probably quite outdated.  My best guess would be that it's referring to the client being a Java applet, which was sort-of in fashion in the late 90s.  In that context, it would make a lot more sense than it does now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not.

RMI is a binary protocol for serializing and sending Java objects between two end-points and you really need those end-points to be JVM's for that to work.

With "web applications" I assume you mean html+http+javascript which would be incredible hard (if at all possible) to use with RMI.

Comment: And the end-points need to be compatible JVM's even.

Comment: and the end points also need compatible code (or enough security clearance to download&execute code)